# TypeScript: how can I use a templated type without specifying the template parameter?

Tags: typescript, templates, generics, types, typescript-generics

Minimal working example:

```
type FuncType<T> = (a: T) => T;

let f1: FuncType<T>; // does not compile
let f2: <T>(a: T) => T; // compiles
```

The problem is that `FuncType` is not defined by me, but comes from a library. It is also way more complex than the example above. I would like to use the templated type exported from the library, instead of having to re-declare it myself (as I do when I annotate `f2`).

Is it even possible? If not, do you know why not?

Thanks for any input, I cannot find anything on this topic

Comment: `declare let f1: FuncType<T>;`

Comment: That does not compile using TS `4.2.3` - which compiler version are you using @RobertoZvjerković?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't type a variable as an un-instantiated generic type.

The reason `<T>(a: T) => T` works is because that is a generic function. `FuncType<T>`, as defined is a generic type that happens to be a function. The difference being that for a generic function the type parameter is decided at call site (for each call) while for a generic type the type is decided when you declare the variable and is unaffected by subsequent calls.

```
type FuncType<T> = (a: T) => T;

declare let f1: FuncType<number>;
f1(1) // ok, T is number
f1("1") // not ok, T is still number
declare let f2: <T>(a: T) => T; 
f2(1) // ok, T is number 
f2("1") // also ok, T is now string
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMYBVwQDwoHxQLxQAUAhgFxQoCU+uKA3ALABQzAJhEgDbEBO0nEYFABmARnLxkaSBgRwAtgCMIPbIyZjCo6gHodUAPYBrADQUoASwDOUOUpXNNAIlFPd+hAaHGzKSzatgC05OWwVlHjYObj4oASFhACZyLGwScioaCjooR0Std0NTc2sw+x5cjXyXNyg9KGJOKwMi339bAwB3KECeCwQAcyA)

If you want to represent any instantiation of `FuncType` your best bet is `FuncType<any>`. But you will have to live with the associated unsafety. (`unknow` and `never` won't work here as `FuncType` is invariant in `T`, they would work for `type FuncType<T> = () => T` and `type FuncType<T> = (a: T) => void` respectively)